# Replace X axis motor with different model

Tags: stepper, motor

Last week, my X-axis stepper motor died. It was a 42SHD0217-24B model. I ordered the same online, but the vendor made a "mistake" and sent me the 17HS3401S model.

I know these motors use a different voltage, so I adjusted the screw on the stepper driver and managed to get a smooth rotation with the new model. I know that these 2 motors have a rotation of 1.8° per step.

My questions are the following:

- Since they have the same rotation angle per step, I shouldn't have to calibrate the new model, right? (I'll use the original wheel)
- Did the vendor send me a motor with inferior performances?
- Will my performances degrade if I use the new motor? (Lecture on motors appreciated). By that I mean: will my top moving speed be affected? Will the motor miss more steps at high speed?

Comment: can you just try it? print a benchy or something and see how it goes.

Comment: Yes I will obivously, but I'm looking for a more theoretical explanation, since I want to understand...

Comment: Not voltage, but amperage (current). Due to the difference in max current, you need to lower Vref of the stepper driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since they have the same rotation angle per step, I shouldn't have to calibrate the new model, right? (I'll use the original wheel)

Yes, you do not have to change anything, other than the Vref of the stepper driver.

> Did the vendor send me a motor with inferior performances?

Yes, the one you received has a lower height, so smaller coils and smaller permanent magnets; basically lower torque.

> Will my performances degrade if I use the new motor?

That depends on the loading of the carriage of the X-axis, it could if it is heavy; you now have less torque available to move the carriage. But, this type is frequently found in 3D printer kits and should work.

Comment: The Vref is adjusted by turning the screw of the driver right? (What I did?). I thought I was adjusting the tension because I normally measure the voltage on the driver. But I gues Ur=R.I :)

Comment: @JPFrancoia Yes you adjust the screw and set the correct Vref according to the stepper driver type to limit current, e.g. for DRV8825 drivers it is `Stepper Current Limit = Vref × 2`.