# X carriage "vibrates" on small segments

Tags: stepper

Following the question I asked here: [Replace X axis motor with different model](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/8735/replace-x-axis-motor-with-different-model/8738?noredirect=1#comment14916_8738)

I have a problem with my new motor. My X-axis is now moved by a 17HS3401S motor, instead of a 42SHD0217-24B motor.

On small segments, like when I need to print an arc with a lot of small straight lines, my printhead "vibrates" instead of having a smooth movement. It seems it stops for a very short amount of time before trying to move again. On longer travels there is no problem.

Do you know if it's because of the motor, or because of something else? (Vref not set properly maybe?)

Comment: what kind of printer? it might be an inherent design thing (Cantilever design, such as the TonXY X1) or it might be fixable by altering the design (Portal/Prusa style), or by tuning the hotend weight (Hypercube)

Comment: vref vref and once more vref. please take a look here https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/1480/how-do-you-make-sure-you-have-the-right-voltage-on-the-trimpots-on-an-a4988-step/1483#1483

Answer (score 1):

The overall torque, and thus the incremental torque is less with your new stepper, this may result in less smooth operation because of moving the weight of the carriage (e.g. when you have a direct extruder mounted on the X carriage).

You could be facing skipping steps, resulting in less accurate prints. Maybe the Vref has not been adjusted correctly, or the stepper is just not working for your application.

Comment: Sounds more likely it's skipping microsteps then catching up before the full step; otherwise there'd be layer shifts.

Answer (score 0):

One other possibility is that the printer is "gap-filling". When there is a space between walls that isn't enough for infill or a roof layer, the slicer can be told to fill the gap, and depending on gap size it often does this with a zig-zaggy motion of the extruder. This is normal; if you wish, you can turn it off, however be aware this can cause those gaps to be visible in top surfaces of your prints.